# Extension for contentblocks in category grid

Tags: magento2, extensions, category-view

does anyone have any idea which extension puts the content blocks at https://www.liquid-life.de/fahrrad/mountainbikes/fullies/enduro/ into the category grid. (3rd tile)

Thanks in advance.

Patrick

Comment: Hi there , do you mean which content ? Is that products u are targetting ?Thanks

Comment: I mean the 3rd and 5th "product"-box with "unsere enduro bikes" and "0% Finanzierung" as content.

Comment: So let me share some debugging tips which i have experienced to find out which block is rendering which content , first you need to find out which template PHTML file belongs to which module/theme by selecting a unique HTML element selector from the browser dev tools and append "test" to the selector or add "test" span tag to that template file to check if it showing in the frontend , and yes there maybe many similar files having this selector , it will ease the process if you are using the right editor such as PHPSTORM , just find it with "ctrl+shift+f" and select scope as app/ or vendor/.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Amasty_Shopby Extension.

Comment: it is not, unfortunately, but thank you. :)

Comment: Please check the Amasty Extensions.
It comes from the Amasty extensions

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. In the meantime we've found the extension. It's Category Grid Callouts from JaJuMa.

https://marketplace.magento.com/jajuma-module-categorycallouts.html

Thanks to all